# Query function does not work for deployed chaincode

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to query the chaincode example 02 that I have deployed in the local blockchain installation.

I have tried both inside and outside vagrant setup as described by hyperledger-fabric docs.

The chaincode go file build successfully and the deployed seems to word.

The invoke function generates the transaction hash, however as soon as I query the state of variable A using the chaincode hash id, it always indicates an error indicating that the chaincode is not deployed successfully.

Comment: please post the json you used for the deploy transaction. Additionally, do you have security enabled or disabled?

Comment: POST host:port/chaincode

{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "query",
  "params": {
      "type": 1,
      "chaincodeID":{
          "name":"mycc"
      },
      "ctorMsg": {
         "function":"query",
         "args":["a"]
      }
  },
  "id": 5
}

Comment: POST host:port/chaincode

{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "deploy",
  "params": {
    "type": 1,
    "chaincodeID":{
        "name": "mycc"
    },
    "ctorMsg": {
        "function":"init",
        "args":["a", "100", "b", "200"]
    },
    "secureContext": "jim"
  },
  "id": 1
}

Comment: Please edit json requests into the question, rather than putting them into comments. They are hard to read without proper formatting

Answer (score 0):

There should be some time gap between a chaincode invocation and the subsequent query. Refer https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ibm-blockchain-issues/issues/20